# Access private variable of class defined in header from class defined in source file

Tags: c++, friend, private-members

> Header.h

```
#pragma once

namespace
{
    class B;
}

namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        class A
        {
        private:
            int i;

        public:
            friend class B;
        };
    }
}
```

> Source.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"

class B
{
public:
    void Run();
};

void B::Run()
{
    n1::n2::A a;
    a.i;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.Run();
}
```

As we can see from above Class A is defined in header file while class B is defined in source file. I want to access private member of Class A from Class B::run(). I am not able to find the way to do this.

Comment: First declaration of `class B;` is inside of anonymous namespace while later is it defined in global namespace.

Comment: Why it was not working when class B is forward declared in unnamed namespace?

Comment: Because friend declaration will befriend `class B` from anonymous namespace, not `class B` from global namespace. You should always properly specify namespace when accessing names from global namespace. `friend class ::B`; Omitting `::` when accessing names from global namespace inevitably leads to program defects.

Comment: You know, if you want `B` to be an inaccessible implementation detail, then declaring it as a private nested class gets the job done without risking ODR violations or polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are forward declaring class B in anonymous namespace

take out class B forward declaration out of the namespace and it should work

like this:

```
#pragma once

class B;


namespace n1
{
    namespace n2
    {
        class A
        {
        private:
            int i;

        public:
            friend class B;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why it was not working when class B is forward declared in unnamed namespace?

Comment: because you are declaring B in an unnamed namespace in header file and defining B in the global namespace (no namespace specifier) in the source file. If you define B in unnamed namespace in the source file then the code would run.
NOTE. generally is not a good practice to declare variables in unnamed namespace in header files.